# Wine64 or Wine 32 for 64-bit Lubuntu 20.04?

Tags: wine, lubuntu, 64bit, 32bit

I am running 64-bit Lubuntu 20.04. I have some old windows executables, which I am not sure if they are 32-bit or 64-bit. As far as I know, 64-bit Windows can run 32-bit executables. Would you therefore recommend if I should install only the 64-bit version of wine on my Lubuntu box, or should I also install the 32-bit version of wine?

Thank you and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu (Lubuntu) 64 bit system, install wine 64-bit, it should work with 32 and 64 windows executable because it will install the 32bit wine library.