# Wine cannot find Wine Gecko despite installing wine-gecko 2.47.1

Tags: ubuntu, wine, html, 64bit

As per the helpful advice given by @GAD3R at [Wine64 or Wine 32 for 64-bit Lubuntu 20.04?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627029/wine64-or-wine-32-for-64-bit-lubuntu-20-04) I installed Wine 5.0 (64-bit) from the Ubuntu 20.04 repository.

On running my windows application I got the following error:

```
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
0009:err:mshtml:create_document_object Failed to init Gecko, returning CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE
```

On some googling I saw that https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290789/iexplorer-under-wine-is-missing-wine-gecko answers how to install Wine Gecko. I carried out the suggested steps as follows:

```
$ wget http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-gecko/2.47.1/wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86_64.msi
$ wine msiexec /i wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86_64.msi
```

I also verified that the installation added the following directory underneath my home directory:

`$ ls -l /home/_myuser_/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/gecko/2.47.1/wine_gecko`

Now when I try to run my windows application again I get the same error:

```
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
0009:err:mshtml:create_document_object Failed to init Gecko, returning CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your application is a 32-bit program, [you’ll need 32-bit Gecko too](https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko):

> For 64 bit (WoW64) Wine, both the x86 and x86_64 packages are required.

```
wget http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-gecko/2.47.1/wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86.msi
wine msiexec /i wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86.msi
```